how can i open the game on my personal app like cheat bypass?
I found someone who could open a game in the bypass application so he opened a bypass then the bypass opened a game after that the application force closed and in the background two activities were created which were running simultaneously namely the game application and the bypass application which displayed the game
but I didn't find the source code for the project, maybe someone knows the source code
